# How to Update a table and prevent triggers from firing except disabling the Trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with 4 million images. This table is participating in `Merge Replication`. I have to update these 4 million images to set Image binary to null as these has been moved to a new table. The moment I will start update query, Merge replication triggers will fire and they will consider that data for merge replication to subscribers and 4 million image rows will be transferred over the wire. I cannot disable merge triggers as this poses a data inconsistency issue.

I want a way so that merge triggers do not fire for this operation. Is there something like `Bulk Insert` for update as well?

Comment: If the merge triggers don't fire, then merge replication will be broken. It seems like you've got to choose what you want: Do you want replication to stay working during this process, or do you want the process to have a low overhead (hint: both is not an option)

Comment: I donot want merge to count this activity in. Merge replication has nothing to do with this data inconsistency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `sp_mergearticlecolumn` stored procedure to drop that specific column from your subscription (temporarily if need be).

More information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188063.aspx